# putting schedulers in CCSequence

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

so basically I have 2 scheduler functions that I would like to put in a CCSequence.

```
id func1 = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(pan1)];
id func2 = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(pan2)];
id seq = [CCSequence actions: func1, func2, nil];
[img runAction:seq];
```

pan1 does a panning from left to right and pan2 does a panning from right to left.

```
-(void) pan1{
    [self schedule:@selector(panLtoR) interval:0.05]; 
}

-(void) pan2{
    [self schedule:@selector(panRtoL) interval:0.05];
}
```

My desired result is to have func1 completed fully before func2 begins.
But right now... func2 begins when func1 is still running. And I can't figure out why.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Added:
Here's how the code of panLtoR looks like

```
-(void) panLtoR{
   [self panLtoR: 1 andY:0.5];
} 

-(void) panLtoR:(float) x andY: (float) y{

   float rightAnchorX = x - m_minAnchorX;

   if(m_curAnchorX <= rightAnchorX)
   {
       m_img.anchorPoint = ccp(m_curAnchorX, y);
       m_curAnchorX += 0.005;
   }

    else{
       [self unschedule:@selector(panLtoR)];
   }
}
```

and panRtoL does similar thing. Basically what I was trying to do is to achieve panning by moving the anchor point and not the position. How can I make it so it finishes the func1 before it starts func2?

Comment: Can you show the code for panning? It might help make a better solution.

Comment: I have added the code to the original post

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down what you have written:

```
id func1 = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(pan1)];
id func2 = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(pan2)];
id seq = [CCSequence actions: func1, func2, nil];
[img runAction:seq];
```

Here, this means call `pan1` and when finished, call `pan2`. This is basically just:

```
[self pan1];
[self pan2];
```

This means that your two schedulers are starting at (almost) the same time. The actions they run internally will be fighting against each other.

---

Though I can't tell exactly what you are trying to accomplish with the limited code, what I expect you want, is something similar to this:

```
id func1 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(-100, 0)];
id func2 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp( 100, 0)];
id seq = [CCSequence actions: func1, func2, nil];
[img runAction:seq];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
So basically I was trying to do panning by anchor points and not positions. So I can't use CCMoveBy.

I have added the code of panLtoR to my original post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you think an answer is useful, you should up vote it. This is the standard way of saying "thank you". If an answer was the most helpful, you should also mark it as correct.